# Custom banner image in Paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal

I need to implement Paypal express checkout and client needs the Paypal checkout to have their own theme (at least the header). Paypal facilitates that by providing an option to upload banner image and a logo. That works fine for me, but I have a different scenario here.

Paypal checkout has 3 (abstract) steps, first where Paypal asks for login, second where it asks you to review shipping address and final the payment confirmation page. I need Paypal checkout to have three different banner images for three different steps. The reason I want to do this is because I want to give a feel of navigation to the user, each banner image will have a tab selected for each step. It might sound confusing, look at the screenshot attached and you'll understand. Its a shot from a checkout on Etsy.com

[image: [Paypal Checkout Screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/q5j2e)]

Is this possible at all? If not, how have the guys at Etsy.com done this? Is there any other way to implement tab/navigation like the header in Paypal Checkout? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Etsy uses a fixed header as well, specifically https://www.etsy.com/images/paypal/paypal-checkout-steps.png
However, the same header is used when you're returned to Etsy's website for order review and order completion.

To answer your question directly; in PayPal itself, you can't set up three different 'headers' for each step in the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob, but i guess **Review & Complete** and **Done** are the Paypal express-checkout steps, aren't they?

Comment: No; I went through the full Etsy checkout just now, and the order review takes place on the Etsy page.